# need regex pattern to split String

Tags: java, regex

**How to split the following string**

```
String str = "(obj.userAge EQUALS  51) AND (obj.userAddress CONTAINS STREET1)";
```

so that I should get

```
string 1 = "obj.userAge EQUALS  512";
string 2 = "obj.userAddress CONTAINS STREET1";
```

I tried with

```
str.split("AND")
```

but I need string without brackets

sometime I can get a string from the database like

```
String str = "(obj.userAge EQUALS  51) AND (obj.userAddress CONTAINS STREET1) OR (obj2.salary >= 3000)";
```

so now `OR` is added.

Comment: The mistake you're making is thinking of this as a job for `split()`.  It's much easier if you approach it as a `find()` operation, as some of the answers demonstrate.  (I prefer [Achintya Jha's solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16300512/20938).)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = "(obj.userAge EQUALS  51) AND (obj.userAddress CONTAINS STREET1)";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\((.+?)\\)");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
    }

}
```

Output:

```
 obj.userAge EQUALS  51
 obj.userAddress CONTAINS STREET1
```

Comment: Just change the `matcher.group()` to `matcher.group(1)`

Answer (score 2):

You should **match** it with this regex

```
(?<=\\().*?(?=\\))
```

`.` matches a single character.

`*` is a quantifier that matches 0 to many preceding character

`.*?` matches 0 to many characters lazily

`(?<=)` is a positive lookbehind which **checks** for a pattern before the current position.So `(?<=a)b` would match `b` only if it's preceded by a

`(?=)` is a positive lookahead which **checks** for a pattern after the current position.So `a(?=b)` would match `a` only if it's followed by `b`

Comment: @MarounMaroun he doesn't need `(`,`)`

Comment: This won't return the `(` and `)`.

Comment: @MarounMaroun see his required output

Answer (score 0):

This regex would generate a group for each of the brackets which you then can retrieve: `\((.*)\)\sAND\s\((.*)\)`

Answer (score 0):

And yet one more (for the fun of it) using guava:

```
 Iterable<String> result = Splitter.on(Pattern.compile("\\(|\\)|AND")).omitEmptyStrings().trimResults().split(input);
```